Problem Compilation with gcc 4.5.1
I am trying to recompile an old software from 2007. The software was compiled with GCC 4.5.1 and uses some Qt4 libraries. I have Ubuntu 20.04, and I tried to install GCC 4.5, but I can't due to some missing libraries. I tried another solution: installing a VM with Ubuntu 10.10, which has GCC 4.5, but I can't install Qt4. Can I have some help, please? Does anybody know something I can do?

Qt4 is long deprecated (see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295 on its removal) with Qt5 now in maintenance mode (next to be deprecated) and Qt6 the development version.  Your software needs updating (porting to newer/supported libraries) I suggest

I understand but i can compile with the right version of qt and gcc

Qt4 hasn't been supported for a long time, so the right Qt will be 6, though 5 is still maintained & supported; so which do you consider the right version?  Qt6 or maintained Qt5; as Qt4 is unsupported.  Your other alternative is to use unofficial (third party) sources, where there were numerous questions asked on this site when 20.04 first released; try exploring some of them

Does this answer your question? Cannot install Qt-4 on Ubuntu 20.04 - Quite Universal Circuit Simulator (QUCS)
